# How to find matching cell values between 2 columns but return the value of another cell. Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

[image]

Image of the excel file is above/attached.

I have data in Column `D` that are matching in Column `A`

What I need is for Column `C` to output the value in Column `B` same row

So in an essence:

`D2` has a value

Find `D2` value in Column `A` and then copy value from column `B` same row.

Ok,

So 
The data in Col A & B are from one source. (Website order records)

The data from Col D are from another source. (Order Shipping processing software).

The problem I ran into is that the OSP is reporting to the site the incorrect shipdate.

So to correctly adjust the info, I have to find & match the order number in Col D from Col A then write the info from Col B to Col C (corresponding cell).

Then after all of that, force it back into SQL DB in the OSP.

**The problems comes in threes

1. Some of the matches does not match whole case.

102-536265-565654

102-536365-565654

Somehow, I am getting a match for those two, when in fact it is not.
2. When it does find the exact match, it doesn't write the value of the cell that is adjacent to it.
3. Col A have 1422 entries, Col D have 2563 entries. Where did all the extras come from ?

See, my problem is a convoluted one, If item 1&2 are resolved, then I can figure out the most critical one (item 3)

I hope that clarifies the lost in oblivion panic at 3am.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. We're not a script writing service (although occasionally people will still do your homework). Besides, I don't find your question too clear. Looking at your spreadsheet, I tend to think that the data model is pretty suboptimal. Essentially, it would be better if it were relational. My question upfront would be, why do columns A and B have repeating items? If that were not the case, things would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

On cell `C2`put:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Copy down to cells on column C.

VLOOKUP will stop at the *first* match ,so if in column `A` you have duplicates it will bring the first matching value of column `B`.

Comment: I'd say this may or may not be a correct solution, because row `A` has duplicates and the Q does not indicate that all values in row `B` for duplicate row `A` entries are identical. If this is the case, the sheet should be different. If this is not the case, then the information how to handle it is missing in the Q.

Comment: Duplicate values on column `A` have the same values on column `B` according to the example.

Comment: I can see that the screenshot of the example table has identical duplicate pairs of rows `A` and `B` but that wasn't my point. My point is that if you provide an answer based on an assumption which the Q does not mention, then you should make that assumption explicit in your A.

Comment: I edited the question by elaborating on the problem. Can you check please